# Force the live USB installs to install Grub to its fallback or secondary install location

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, grub

Turns out that my particular laptop has a bug in it where the BIOS firmware keeps the software looking for the boot file in the fallback directory where GRUB doesn't install it and Linux crashes telling me that `grub-install` failed.

Is there a way to force the live USB installs to install GRUB to its fallback or secondary install location so it will be found by both the software and the computer?

I'm looking for a way to get the live USB install to install to its fallback or secondary option so the computer can force the software to look there, but with the install going there it would not trigger a critical failure and stop the install.

I have tried installing, letting it fail and then installing GRUB manually, but *as I don't know where the fallback location is* I run into the same issues as Linux and have no clue if there is more going on after the `grub-install`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I sorted my issue. I found out where to add --force-extra to place the Grub install into it's fallback location and now I have installed Several Distros (Short Chinese/Japanese for whatever reason). I personally cannot read that language  anyhow so it is not something I'm too sad about and may have something to do with my not being able to install. The ENTIRE problem was the BIOS blocking any attempt to manually install Grub in it's fallback so the computer could see  it.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you talk about *boot file* indicates you have an UEFI system and are not using legacy BIOS compatibility.

The fallback/secondary boot file pathname is defined in the UEFI specification and is architecture-specific. For 64-bit x86 hardware architecture (= typical modern PCs), the location can be defined as `\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi` on a FAT32 filesystem (or with newer UEFI versions, any FAT filesystem type other than exFAT). On other architectures, the `x64` part is replaced by a short identifier of the respective architecture. The pathname is supposedly case-insensitive, but some UEFI firmware implementions are known to be erroneously case-sensitive here.

When installing the UEFI version of GRUB, giving `grub-install` the option `--removable` will install the bootloader in the fallback/secondary location. Alternatively, using the `--force-extra-removable` option will attempt to install it *both* to the standard location for an installed OS, *and* the fallback/secondary location. The installers of some distributions include check-boxes for these options in their bootloader settings menu (often in the "advanced" section).

But if your distribution of choice fails to provide this option, Linux installers almost universally offer command prompt access. If you have booted from the installation media, one of the *Linux virtual consoles* will almost universally have a root command prompt available, once you have made the initial keyboard/language selections in the installation UI. You can switch between virtual consoles using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> function key strokes: usually the installer UI will be on <kbd>F1</kbd>, and the other function keys offer access to the root prompt and various installer diagnostics. If you have started the installation using a live Linux media that includes a full desktop interface, opening a command prompt window should be pretty simple in most desktop environments.

On a UEFI system, there should be an EFI System Partition (ESP for short): it's a small (often less than 512MB) partition that's intended for bootloader files of any and all installed OSs.

On Linux, this partition is often mounted at `/boot/efi`, so the fallback/secondary bootloader could be seen at `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`, and the primary bootloader path for an installed Linux system would be of the form `/boot/efi/EFI/<name of Linux distribution>/*.efi`.

However, some distributions may leave the ESP normally unmounted, and only mount it while actually in the process of updating the bootloader.

The last step in UEFI-style bootloader installation is to write a *UEFI NVRAM boot variable* which will tell the firmware exactly where the bootloader of an installed OS is located (one variable for each installed OS). This is something completely new that had no equivalent in legacy BIOS: unfortunately it seems hardware manufacturers have often tried to make UEFI as legacy-BIOS-like as possible, and as a result, the UEFI firmware configuration menus ("BIOS settings") often don't have good tools for manipulating these boot variables.

In Linux, UEFI boot variables can be most conveniently viewed and edited with the `efibootmgr` command. If it reports an error like "UEFI variables are not available on this system", it might indicate that you have accidentally booted the installation media in legacy BIOS-compatible mode: in this mode, the necessary API between the firmware and the running OS (called UEFI Runtime Services) will not be available until the system is booted in UEFI native mode.

Comment: the fact that you posted about that is supposed to happen tells me that other than READING to see that I have changed it back and forth three ways to Sunday as what was SUPPOSED to happen wasn't and that is the issue. I have been following steps like this for over a Decade and THIS time None of them worked until I found an Operating System that fulfilled the MAIN issue and now as that system is not fully to my liking I am trying to figure out a way to change it so it does. I'm fine with people at least attempting to solve things, but if I can avoid it, covering the same ground I have covered..

Comment: At least this answers one of my questions as far as WHERE the backup or fallback directory may be located as I am starting to find that to fix my issue I am going to have to design what and how I want to install my system and as this will teach me HOW to FIX my issue and not just put a band-aid on it. So Thanks for that. :)

Comment: someone pointed out that I''m only giving the details of MY experiences without the context that I used to fix my problem. This probably will explain WAY better than I ever could..  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1832282. notice the word BUG peppered throughout... Kind of says that NORMAL fixes are not going to work.